# modprobe in setuid contextmodprobe in setuid context

Tags: environment-variables, root, kernel-modules, setuid, modprobe

In [CVE-2017-0358](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1072&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=), author notes that

> The issue is that /sbin/modprobe is not designed to run in a setuid
>   context. As the manpage of modprobe explicitly points out
>
> ```
> The MODPROBE_OPTIONS environment variable can also be used
> to pass arguments to modprobe.
> ```

`modprobe` is supposed to add/remove modules from kernel, which anyway requires root privileges.
So what does it mean to say that **"modprobe is not designed to run in setuid context"**?

Comment: The explanation is in the _very next paragraph_.

Comment: I understood the whole exploit. My question is, to run the modprobe, you need root privileges. How different is setting `uid` compared to using running it as `sudo`?